# Unable to use http://localhost after upgrading from Ubuntu 15.10 -> 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2, 15.10, lamp, php7

I installed lamp on my 15.10. It was working. Yesterday I have updated my ubuntu Computer 15.10 to 16.04. I tried to access localhost without success.

I have tried `service apache2 restart` and recieved the following error:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-06-25 13:50:20 IST; 1min 0s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5414 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 apache2[5414]:  *
Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 apache2[5414]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 apache2[5414]: Output of config test was:
Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 apache2[5414]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 apache2[5414]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 apache2[5414]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 25 13:50:20 ajay-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it guys! No worries!

I came to understand that 16.04 ships with php 7.0 rather than 5.0. My guess is I had modules of php 5.0 installed for apache.

**Installing php7.0 apache module:**

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

**Disabling php5 module, since we got no php5.0:**

```
sudo a2dismod php5
```

**Enabled php7 module:**

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

**restarted apache:**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

that's it fellas

Comment: Nice, than please accept your own answer so we know it's already solved ;)

Comment: 'I can accept my answer in two days' says the prompt when I click it, may be because I got less points?